# Python date comparison with string output/format

Tags: python, date, time, scripting

I'm currently trying to writing a script to automate a function at work, but I'm not intimately familiar with Python. I'm trying to take a XML dump and compare a specific entry's date to see if the time has passed or not.

The date is in a particular format, given:

```
<3-letter Month> <DD> <HH:MM:SS> <YYYY> <3-letter Timezone>
```

For example:

```
May 14 20:11:20 2014 GMT
```

I've parsed out a string in that raw form, and need to somehow compare it with the current time to find out if the time has passed or not. That said, I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how I should go about either formatting my text, or choosing the right mask/time format in Python.

I've been messing around with different variations of the same basic format:

```
if(trimmed < time.strftime("%x") ):
```

Trimmed is the clean date/time string. Time is derived from *import time*.

Is there a simple way to fix this or will I have to dig into converting the format etc.? I know the above attempt is simplistic, but I'm still very new to Python. Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: What is in `trimmed`?  If (as it appears) `time` has an actual time value in it, why not make a time value from what you have parsed, and compare that to `time`?

Comment: Ahh sorry! Trimmed is the tag free formatted date/time entry. Time is derived directly from the standard library time. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use combination of gmtime (for GMT time),mktime and datetime.

```
from time import gmtime,mktime
from datetime import datetime

s = "May 14 20:11:20 2014 GMT"
f = "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT"
dt = datetime.strptime(s, f)
gmt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(gmtime()))
if dt<gmt:
    print(dt)
else:
    print(gmt)
```

Comment: You can use %Z instead of 'GMT' for more flexibility

Comment: To clarify, dt is the newly formatted date time string and gmt is the relative time from epoch to dt - right?

Comment: I changed some superficial things around for my output, but thanks a lot! Its functionally exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No, here dt is a datetime.datetime() type var, parsed from string.